# Compare two set of object and create new set with javascript and form jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Hi i am new to react and javascript

I have two set of objects

set1

```
const set1 = {
  men: { value: "men", label: "Men", type: "select" },
  women: { value: "women", label: "Women", type: "select" },
  kids: { value: "kids", label: "Kids", type: "select" },
};
```

and set2

```
const set2 = {
  men: { code: "men", title: "Men" },
  women: { code: "men", title: "Men" },
};
```

I want to compare both the set of object and if key is same i want to get the result as new object

```
const resultobj = {
  men: { value: "men", label: "Men", type: "select" },
  women: { value: "women", label: "Women", type: "select" },
};
```

And i want to display label from result obj in a div using jsx   exmaple

```
return <div>{resultobj.label}</div>;
```

Comment: I think what you're looking for is an intersection of sets. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set no?

Comment: is `resultobj` the expected result? and by which property do you compare?

Comment: @Mario . Yes.and need to display label. I want to compare with the key. If key is same . Then I want to show that first set in resultsobj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the intersection for keys and then get first object values with intersected keys

```js
const set1 = {
  men: { value: "men", label: "Men", type: "select" },
  women: { value: "women", label: "Women", type: "select" },
  kids: { value: "kids", label: "Kids", type: "select" },
};

const set2 = {
  men: { code: "men", title: "Men" },
  women: { code: "men", title: "Men" },
};



let keys = Object.keys(set1).filter(key => key in set2)

let result = {} 
keys.forEach((key)=>{
      result = {...result,...{[key]:set1[key]}}
})

console.log(result)
```

for displaying label of all the values in the object we need to iterate over the values and display them

```
{Object.values(result).map((value)=><div>{value.label}</div>)}
```

Comment: Ok I will try this. But I want to display the label from resultobj in a div. How can I do it?

Comment: Yes it worked, Thak you but if  women: {value: "women", label: "Women" , type: "select" "options: 1: {label: "lady", value_string: "1"} 2: {label: "girl", value_string: "2"}"} . How can i access value inside option . option has label . i want to get the label inside option.

Comment: @Rspp please provide the data on how it looks or else post an another question we will be happy to help

Comment: I have posted the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62528353/access-inner-object-and-form-jsx @aravind_reddy

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following example

```js
const set1 = {
  men: { value: "men", label: "Men", type: "select" },
  women: { value: "women", label: "Women", type: "select" },
  kids: { value: "kids", label: "Kids", type: "select" },
};

const set2 = {
  men: { code: "men", title: "Men" },
  women: { code: "men", title: "Men" },
};

// get keys of both arrays
const array1 = Object.keys(set1);
const array2 = Object.keys(set2);

// get interesction
const diff = array1.filter((entry) => array2.includes(entry));

// reduce to result object
const output = diff.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
  previousValue[currentValue] = set1[currentValue];

  return previousValue;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Update 0

Because you can have 1 or more results you must list them for example

```
return (
  <ul>
    {output.map(entry => <li>{entry.label}</li>)}
  </ul>
)
```

Update 1

The data you show is not properly formatted, please try the following

```js
const data1 = {
  women: {
    value: "women",
    label: "Women",
    type: "select",
    options: {
      1: {
        label: "lady",
        value_string: "1",
      },
      2: {
        label: "girl",
        value_string: "2",
      },
    },
  },
};

for (const key in data1.women.options) {
  console.log(data1.women.options[key].label);
}
```

I understand you can get more than one data, if it is the case you can try the following

```js
const data2 = {
  women: {
    value: "women",
    label: "Women",
    type: "select",
    options: {
      1: {
        label: "lady",
        value_string: "1",
      },
      2: {
        label: "girl",
        value_string: "2",
      },
    },
  },
  men: {
    value: "women",
    label: "Women",
    type: "select",
    options: {
      1: {
        label: "lady",
        value_string: "1",
      },
      2: {
        label: "girl",
        value_string: "2",
      },
    },
  },
};

for (const property in data2) {
  for (const key in data2[property].options) {
    console.log(data2[property].options[key].label);
  }
}
```

Now, to render in react you will need to use map, for this you can pass each object to an array in which you will then use map, see the following example

Following the logic of the second example

```
let output1 = [];

for (const property in data2) {
  for (const key in data2[property].options) {
    output1 = [...output1, data2[property].options[key]];
  }
}

return (
  <ul>
    output1.map(entry => <li>{entry.label}</li>)
  </ul>
)
```

See

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

This is a very common scenario, I recommend you keep reference to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33034768/615274

Comment: Ok..and how I can display the label from result object in jsx?  <div>{resultobj.label}</div> ?

Comment: Thank you Mario. It works . I have one more query. If object  women: {value: "women", label: "Women" , type: "select" "options: 1: {label: "lady", value_string: "1"} 2: {label: "girl", value_string: "2"}"} . Here i want to acess label inside option. How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach and key values

```js
const set1 = {
  men: { value: "men", label: "Men", type: "select" },
  women: { value: "women", label: "Women", type: "select" },
  kids: { value: "kids", label: "Kids", type: "select" },
};
const set2 = {
  men: { code: "men", title: "Men" },
  women: { code: "men", title: "Men" },
};
filter={}
Object.entries(set2).forEach((o)=>{
  Object.entries(set1).forEach(k=>{
       if(o[0]==k[0]) filter[k[0]]=k[1]
  })
})

console.log(filter)
```