# Access inner Object and form Jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two set of objects

```
const obj1 = {
    men: {
      value: "men",
      attribute_label: "Men",
      type: "select",
      attribute_options: {
        1: { label: "infant", value_string: "1" },
        2: { label: "baby", value_string: "2" }
      }
    },
    women: {
      value: "women",
      attribute_label: "Women",
      type: "select",
      attribute_options: {
        1: { label: "infant", value_string: "1" },
        2: { label: "baby", value_string: "2" }
      }
    },
    kids: {
      value: "kids",
      attribute_label: "Kids",
      type: "select",
      attribute_options: {
        7: { label: "infant", value_string: "1" },
        8: { label: "baby", value_string: "2" }
      }
    }
  };
```

and set2

```
const obj2 = {
men: { code: "men", title: "Men" },
women: { code: "men", title: "Men" }
};
```

I want to compare both the set of object and if key is same i want to get the result as new object

```
    const resultobj = {
     men: {
  value: "men",
  attribute_label: "Men",
  type: "select",
  attribute_options: {
    1: { label: "infant", value_string: "1" },
    2: { label: "baby", value_string: "2" }
  }
},
women: {
  value: "women",
  attribute_label: "Women",
  type: "select",
  attribute_options: {
    1: { label: "infant", value_string: "1" },
    2: { label: "baby", value_string: "2" }
  }
}
    };
```

And i want to display label from result obj and show label inside option . I have label in Men and inside option i have other 2 label boy and guy. Same in the case of Women. So i want to display the value inside option as well. Example format i have mentioned.

```
Men 

boy Guy

Women

Lady  Girl
```

Comment: I don't know if i understand, you want to create a new object where the keys are common in the previous 2 objects? And which object should you take, the one from set1 or set2? Or a combination?

Comment: Yes. and i want to display the label and the values inside option as well

Comment: Your input is still invalid (`"options": 1: {label: "boy"`). Posting compilable code is the absolute bare minimum requirement. Any code editor will highlight the errors in your object literal.

Comment: @Rspp `("options":1:{label:"boy"}) `isn't a valid object syntax in js do you mean options is an array ?

Comment: Yes in array. while creating the object format i missed it

Comment: then please update the question with proper data @Rspp

Comment: So you mean `options` is an `array of objects`?

Comment: yes array of objects

Comment: @ aravind_reddy. I have updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const set1 = {
          men: {value: 'men',label: 'Men',type: 'select',
        options: [
          { 1: { label: 'boy', value_string: '1' } },
          { 2: { label: 'Guy', value_string: '2' } },
        ],
      },
      women: {value: 'women',label: 'Women',type: 'select',
        options: [
          { 1: { label: 'lady', value_string: '1' } },
          { 2: { label: 'girl', value_string: '2' } },
        ],
      },
      kids: {value: 'kids',label: 'Kids',type: 'select',
        options: [
          { 1: { label: 'infant', value_string: '1' } },
          { 2: { label: 'baby', value_string: '2' } },
        ],
      },
        };

const set2 = {
  men: { code: "men", title: "Men" },
  women: { code: "Women", title: "Women" },
};



let keys = Object.keys(set1).filter(key => key in set2)

let result = {} 
keys.forEach((key)=>{
      result = {...result,...{[key]:set1[key]}}
})

console.log(result)
```

and for showing the labels

```
{Object.keys(result).map(key => {
    return (
      <Fragment key={key}>
        <h3>{result[key].attribute_label}</h3>
        {Object.values(result[key].attribute_options).map(option => (
          <span key={option.value_string} style={{ paddingRight: "10px" }}>
            {option.label}
          </span>
        ))}
      </Fragment>
    );
  })}
```

working link https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-dream-x3vi7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Rspp i have added my answer

Comment: when i check in browser console, options comes like this `options: {1: {…}, 2: {…}}` . And when i expand it shows `options: 1: {label: "boy", value_string: "1"} 2: {label: "Guy", value_string: "2"} ` . When i expand it i get it as : `options: 1: {label: "boy", value_string: "1"} 2: {label: "Guy", value_string: "2"}`  . So for this case the above code will work? @aravind_reddy

Comment: I am getting this error  ** attribute_options.map is not a function**

Comment: but in the question you mentioned options is an array right ?

Comment: can you reporoduce your scenario in codesandbox or something that would be help us to help you

Comment: But I'm getting confused with the format. It's object and then array and then object.

Comment: This the format. So can you do with this format please

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-aryabhata-6rx0d?file=/src/App.js . I have changed data fromat here

Comment: @Rspp i have updated the answer and here is the working sanbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-dream-x3vi7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It worked. Thank you for your support :) . You can update your answer here as well. One with object and one with array. It will be helpful for others who are looking the same

Comment: its better if you could update the question with your correct data bcz that is more relevant here... i have edited ur question as well

Answer (score 0):

Considering `options` as an array of objects you can use below utility to fetch the matching items of `set2` from `set1`.

```js
const set1 = {
  men: {
    value: 'men',
    label: 'Men',
    type: 'select',
    options: [
      { 1: { label: 'boy', value_string: '1' } },
      { 2: { label: 'Guy', value_string: '2' } },
    ],
  },
  women: {
    value: 'women',
    label: 'Women',
    type: 'select',
    options: [
      { 1: { label: 'lady', value_string: '1' } },
      { 2: { label: 'girl', value_string: '2' } },
    ],
  },
  kids: {
    value: 'kids',
    label: 'Kids',
    type: 'select',
    options: [
      { 1: { label: 'infant', value_string: '1' } },
      { 2: { label: 'baby', value_string: '2' } },
    ],
  },
}

const set2 = {
  men: { code: 'men', title: 'Men' },
  women: { code: 'men', title: 'Men' },
}

let finalObj = Object.keys(set2).reduce((result, key) => {
  result[key] = set1[key]
  return result
}, {})

console.log(finalObj)
```

Here `finalObj` will contain the resultant object, which you can use for displaying labels in the UI.

Here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-shadow-d78ov?file=/src/App.js) for working example of displaying in react application. I just created a sample application where I have used this utility for formatting the data and the same data for displaying the way you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But i want to get the label inside the option also to display from the final object.  Men  and below that  label from option 

boy Guy

Comment: I have added sandbox link for displaying the labels the way you want. Please have a look [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-shadow-d78ov?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: when i check in browser console, options comes like this `options: {1: {…}, 2: {…}}`   . And when i expand it shows  ` options:
1: {label: "boy", value_string: "1"}
2: {label: "Guy", value_string: "2"} `  . When i expand it i get it as : 
`options:
1: {label: "boy", value_string: "1"}
2: {label: "Guy", value_string: "2"} `   . So for this case the above  code will work? @Nithish

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-aryabhata-6rx0d?file=/src/App.js Sandbox with data

Comment: In the question you mentioned `options` is an `array of objects` . But in the link you shared you used `attribute_options` as an object. Can you please let us know the structure of your input. Only then we can help you.

Comment: In the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-aryabhata-6rx0d?file=/src/App.js) you shared if you change `attribute_options:{1:{label:"infant",value_string:"1"},2:{label:"baby",value_string:"2"}}` to  `attribute_options:[{1:{label:"infant",value_string:"1"}},{2:{label:"baby",value_string:"2"}}]` in all the objects then it'll work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you in comparing the objects here, You can first take the entries of object and apply filter and inside that see if the key is included in the second object. once done You can use `Object.fromEntries` to create new Object. Here is the working example:

```js
var set1 = {
  men: { value: "men", label: "Men", type: "select", "options": [ {label: "boy", value_string: "1"}, {label: "Guy", value_string: "2"}] },
  women: { value: "women", label: "Women", type: "select", "options": [ {label: "lady", value_string: "1"} , {label: "girl", value_string: "2"}] },
  kids: { value: "kids", label: "Kids", type: "select" ,"options": [ {label: "infant", value_string: "1"} , {label: "baby", value_string: "2"}] },
};

var set2 = {
  men: { code: "men", title: "Men" },
  women: { code: "men", title: "Men" },
};

var filteredObj = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(set1).filter(([k,v])=>Object.keys(set2).includes(k)));

console.log(filteredObj);
```

Comment: Also i want to show label inside option .Expected like this

Men 

boy Guy

Comment: @Rspp you can edit your question and show us the expected output in JSON form.

Comment: @Rspp If I understand it correctly you need  to show `value` `{ label: 'boy', value_string: '1' , value:'men'}` inside options, right?

Comment: No. Not like that . in jsx if  i  return <div>{resultobj.label}</div> gives label(Men). but want to return option label as well.

Comment: As per your answer will get final output filteredObj . That is correct. Now i want to display the values inside the option . inside option i have label. That value in  label